# Detectando queries lentas no MySQL da Rackspace

Tags: mysql, query, desempenho

Existe uma maneira fácil de ver as queries lentas no MySQL da Rackspace?

Eu tentei [essas instruções](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/access-slow-query-and-general-logs-for-cloud-databases), mas são muito complicadas...

[Post original em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275849/how-to-detect-mysql-slow-queries-when-using-rackspace-database)

Comment: Parece não ser muito complicado, só 5 passos.. Basicamente, o que pedem pra fazer, é ativar o slow_query_log escrevendo numa tabela, pra você depois ler dela..

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.